# Loading multiband image using brick() fails?

Tags: r, raster-functions

Here's my working environment, R version 3.4.4/R Studio version 1.0.143, below is the line of code that fails :

```
Image<- brick(ImageName.tiff)
```

brings the error below :

```
Error in .local(.Object, ...) : 

Error in .rasterObjectFromFile(x, objecttype = "RasterBrick", ...) : 
  Cannot create a RasterLayer object from this file. (file does not exist)
```

A previous Q&A (https://stackoverflow.com/q/53237802/820534) is not helpful. I've confirmed that `libtiff5` is installed in the Ubuntu 16.04 box I am using.

Answer (score 1):

```
Error in .rasterObjectFromFile(x, objecttype = "RasterBrick", ...) : 
  Cannot create a RasterLayer object from this file. (file does not exist)
```

says the file does not exist. You've got the name or the path wrong. Use the correct path.